# Twilio Autopilot - sourceChannel

Tags: twilio-api

Is there a way to check the source channel (ie Alexa vs Programmable Chat) in the functions to direct to different answers depending on the source? I found some sourceChannel references in the docs, but I couldn't figure out how to reference those properties in a function.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api/query#query-properties

Answer (score 0):

If you use Twilio functions behind your Autopilot task, it is possible.
In the event parameter you'll find the channel.
Eg. Checking if facebook else Whatsapp

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
   let channel = "";
   if(event.Channel == "messageing.facebook-messenger"){
      channel = "Facebook";
   }else{
      channel = "Whatsapp";
   }
   responseObject = {
     "actions": [
     {
        "say": `Your channel is ${channel}`
     }
     ]
   };
   return callback(null, responseObject);
}
```